# Grunt lodash template won't map and return an array, can't figure out proper syntax

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, build-automation, lodash

**Goal:** Below is the grunt task. It's job, concatenate and obfuscate the files passed in via an array of strings. Order is important, and order is already set. Typical and very basic grunt uglify setup.

**Problem:** The array, while in the correct order, is full of relative urls, that need prepended the string 'app/'. `app.bummer_js` you'll see below in first example, is an array manually prefixed, to prove the task works and the lodash templates are working as expected. The following examples, are to illustrate that any expression inside the template, is not properly returning the expected array.

```
# assume the following arrays are available from another file
app =
  js: [
    'path/to/file/lib/dependency.js'
    'path/to/file/app.js'
  ]
  bummer_js: [
    'app/path/to/file/lib/dependency.js'
    'app/path/to/file/app.js'
  ]

module.exports =
  prod:
    options:
      banner:"<%= banner %>"
    files:
      # straight array reference in template, **manually** prefixed with 'app/' base dir in the app config, 
      # src order maintained, works great except there's a manual process to it.
      "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":"<%= app.bummer_js %>"

      # simply mapping the array fails in grunt, not a recognized pattern or not written because src files were empty.
      # when console logged, the array appears correct and in proper src order
      "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":"<%= _.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`) %>"

      # none of these syntax styles below work either
      # remove '=' to have it evaluated by lodash
      "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":"<% _.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`) %>"
      "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":"<%= app.js.map((file)=>`app/${file}`) %>"

      # wrapping template in brackets turns the contents into an array, but src order is lost (i believe this is from going from an object to an array)
      "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":"{<%= _.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`) %>}"
```

It's very important the src order is maintained for the concatenation part of Uglify. And after 100's of attempts at writing the correct lodash syntax, I cannot find how to write the template to return a mapped array as I need. The only way the task completes, is when the expression is wrapped in `{}`, providing me with a useless bundle.

**tldr;** What is the proper lodash syntax to map an array, so that a recognized pattern is returned to Node/Grunt's system. All I need is an array of files prefixed with a string! It's soooooo simple in theory, and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Why not do the map before the module.exports? You'd have your array dynamically created but no syntax issue after.

Comment: Good idea. I've tried it, and grunt doesn't replace the template strings, templating no strings outside the imported tasks scope.

Answer (score 0):

`prod.files` are a templates. Probably Your script, that used the template, don't have access to 'app' variable.

### compile template

```
  # straight array reference in template, **manually** prefixed with 'app/' base dir in the app config, 
  # src order maintained, works great except there's a manual process to it.
  "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":_.template("<%= app.bummer_js %>")({app: app})

  # simply mapping the array fails in grunt, not a recognized pattern or not written because src files were empty.
  # when console logged, the array appears correct and in proper src order
  "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":_.template("<%= _.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`) %>")({app: app})

  # none of these syntax styles below work either
  # remove '=' to have it evaluated by lodash
  "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":_.template("<% _.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`) %>")({app: app})
  "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":_.template("<%= app.js.map((file)=>`app/${file}`) %>")({app: app})

  # wrapping template in brackets turns the contents into an array, but src order is lost (i believe this is from going from an object to an array)
  "<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js":_.template("{<%= _.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`) %>}")({app: app})
```

### export app

```
module.exports =
  app: app,
  prod:
    options: ...
```

In this case You must manualy add `app` to Your script when You compile a template, e.g.

```
tmpls = require('your/module')
_.template(tmpls.prod.files['<%= dirs.build %>/js/app.js'])({app: tmpls.app})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I've tried your solutions, and (app: app) is undefined.   

Also, if this string below is provided, an array is logged as expected, indicating app is within scope of the template when .map is performed.  

    "<%= console.log(_.map(app.js,(file)=>`app/${file}`)) %>"

Comment: I am certain the 'app' variable is being passed properly.